# MySQL: Quicker to check/insert duplicate row, or insert and ignore failure?

Tags: mysql

MySQL (MyISAM)

Often duplicate rows will try to be added (which aren't allowed because of the unique index).

Which is quicker?

1) Check if row exists. If not then insert.

or

2) Insert row regardless. Ignore failure if it already exists.

Comment: I assume that option 2 is `INSERT IGNORE ...` (as opposed generating an error and suppressing it)

Answer (score 2):

Well I'm not a MySQL expert, but option 1 is taking two steps/cycles. Option 2 is only taking one step. Option 1 has two return values (1 to see if data is there, 2 usually the inserted id), and Option 2 only returns 1 value.

I have always done option 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you use MyISAM, 1) is not really an option because you'd need to use a transaction which is not supported by MyISAM.

Comment: +1 for bringing up concurrency issues.  You could do option 1 with MyISAM and a table lock, but that's adding yet another two steps.  Doing option 1 without any kind of interlocking will fail at some point when two processes try to add at the same time.